# Hibernate order by property from extending entity

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, criteria-api, hibernate-criteria

I have an abstact class A

```
public abctract class A{}
```

and 2 implementing classes B and C

```
public class B extends A{
    private String bProperty;
    private String b2Property; 
}
public class C extends A{
    private String cProperty;
}
```

There is no relation in database between **bProperty**,**b2Property** and **cProperty**, but in my grid on ui they need to be displayed in the same column (concatenated for B). 
What is more in my grid I have paging in which I need eg. 25 results on each page.

To achive that I need to sort my entities by the following order **bProperty**, **cProperty**, **b2Property**.

Is there any way to create criteria for class A, and still be able to define ordering based on the mentioned fields and avoid org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: bProperty of: A?